# Are wooden kitchen counters meant to be shaved (with a planer) to continue looking tidy?

Tags: kitchen-counters

After 15 years of use, my 20"x14" cutting board looks tired.

[image: wooden cutting board]

Now that I'm looking to put in fresh kitchen countertops, I'm contemplating using the same kind of wood (do identify the type if you know) for a far larger area, but I know that its upkeep could become a hassle. Normally I'd say that after 20 years I'd be ready for another countertop anyway, and it'd be good if it lasts that much. The trouble is that I would hate it if it already looks tired after 4-5 years.

How do you maintain a wooden kitchen countertop? I have the impression that no amount of cleaning will keep it fresh enough. It may be necessary to shave off (with a planer? with a belt sander?) a thin layer every 3-5 years and oil (with a food safe product) the newly exposed wood. At that rate it would continue looking decent for 25 years, but then, just like a hardwood floor, would have reached the tail end of its lifetime. With this kind of care, would I be asking too much if I use the countertop as a gigantic cutting board?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No no no on the planer.  Unless you can totally remove the top and send it through an industrial planer that can do it all at once, a planer is a terrible idea.  It will just be full of ridges, you will have bad edges, and probably take off too much.

Normally I would hit something like this with 40 grit on an orbital sander - not belt - and then slowly work my way to 300-400 grit.  Oil it a few times over the next two weeks, and you are good to go (have rehabbed many butcher block counters).